# how to create a layout window using pysimpleguiqt to select the files from the local system

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to create a popup window using pysimpleguiqt to select files through popup window

`folder = sg.PopupGetFolder('Image folder to open', default_path='')`

i want the popup window to select files through window

Comment: will u provide me the  result to the question please....